# Mysql MYISAM table keeps crashing

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql server where the same big table keeps crashing now and then, usully during high load. The table in phpmyadmin gets marked as crashed and need to be repaired. Usually i have to do a myisamchk -r table.MYI to repair it which takes quite a while.

That table is about 6.4 GB with 23.500.000 rows in it and running MYISAM. Is my best bet to convert that table to INODB and how much will that help? or is there anything i can do to my MySQL config to help?

The server has 8GB of RAM and My MySQL config looks like this.

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server.servername.com.err
performance-schema=0
table_open_cache=2000
innodb_strict_mode="ON"
sql_mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
open_files_limit=40000

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 64M
myisam-sort-buffer-size        = 64M
myisam-recover-options         = FORCE

# SAFETY #
skip-external-locking
max-allowed-packet             = 128M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
innodb                         = FORCE

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 32
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 286
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 512
group-concat-max-len           = 1048576

# INNODB #
#innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-log-buffer-size         = 16M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 4G

# LOGGING #
# log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
# slow-query-log                 = 1
# slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log

max_allowed_packet=268435456
innodb_file_per_table=1
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet             = 128M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size                = 768M
sort_buffer_size               = 256M
read_buffer                    = 2M
write_buffer                   = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: what does "table keeps crashing" mean?  what happens?  what do you see?

Comment: The table in phpmyadmin get's marked as crashed and need to be repaired. Usully i have to do a myisamchk -r table.MYI to repair it.

Comment: Crashing regularly is not normal. You should examine the MySQL Server error log, it might have clues for why the crashes are occurring.

Comment: Today was the first crash in like 3 months and before that 3 times in 2 months so that's the timeline when it happens and i belive it is because of an OOM issue each time.

Comment: OOM is a possible explanation. You can search system logs to confirm it. There are suggestions here for several possible logs to search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you will post additional information requested, we will help you survive your requirements with configuration suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If OOM triggers the "crashes", then there is too much running on that machine and/or the processes are using too much ram.

It sounds like you have a mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB tables:

```
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 4G  -- change to 3G
```

That *might* decrease the frequency of OOMs.

Yes, moving to InnoDB is a good idea for many reasons, including avoiding the need to "repair" that big table.  Caution: That big table may grow to 15GB when switching to InnoDB.

Comment: Hi
I do not have a single InnoDB table, only MyIsam currently. That's why i was asking if it would help to convert that single table to InnoDB or not. That table is taking like 90% of the hits from all traffic on the website as it handles statistics. Would it improve only repair issue or would there be any negative impact except for size ?

Comment: @EriskssonJ - It depends.  Indexes have significantly different designs between the engines.  _Usually_ the differences don't matter.  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a few of the common queries -- both `SELECT` and writes (insert/update/delete).

Comment: @EriskssonJ - For example, something as simple as incrementing a "Like" or "View" counter has a radically different impact when implemented in MyISAM (table locking -- fast, but blocking everything else) versus InnoDB (risk of deadlocks).